# calculate total based on form selection

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am a php novice but really need to get a simple function to work.

Ok here goes.

I have a field in mysql database called price.  What I need to do is multiply this price based on what user select from select options.

I can display price ok with the following.

```
include 'mysql_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM fuel_price WHERE id = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<p>" . $person ['Price'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $person ['FuelType'] . "</p>";
}

// Make a MySQL Connection
include 'mysql_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT FuelType, SUM(Price) FROM fuel_price"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

How do I create query to caculate total based on quantity of litres user selects??

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply it (you need to add the amount of liters to your query via PHP):

```
SELECT Price * 50 FROM …
```

If you are just starting to learn PHP, better use PDO or MySQLi for DB-connections. You are also including 'mysql_connect.php' twice, which is not necessary, if a DB-connection is established once.

Comment: via `$_REQUEST['qtylitres']`, but I would use an `<input type="text" />` to provide more options to the user. And which car has a 900 liters tank?

Answer (score 0):

just get the value selected from your form.

`$quantity =  $_GET['qtylitres']; 
//multiply this $quantity with the value from db`


you should show us your db table structure.

Comment: Ok table has three cols


ID 1 FuelType Oil Price 1.145


Table name is fuel_price

Thanks

Comment: if that's all the data u need... I'm wondering why you need a database. You could hard-code these values into variables.

Answer (score -1):

Get the value passed with form. you may use the method as same as used in form (POST/GET) or REQUEST to get the form value i.e:

```
 $qty = $_REQUEST['liter_qty'];

"SELECT Price * {$qty} AS Total FROM fuel_price WHERE id = '1'"
```